# IONIC and Angular as Front-End developments

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework

What I want to get from IONIC and Angularjs right now is just using that front-end library like CSS and JS. So far we use bootstrap and jquery for frontend framework, and Laravel for its backend. Now I want to switch from Bootstrap to Ionic, and from jquery to AngularJS.

In this case, I will use ionic not only for hybird app development (what I have been doing so far), but right now I also want to use it for web too.

Last Framework I use to build web app:

- Laravel
- Jquery
- Bootstrap

But the framework I want to use right now are:

- Laravel,
- AngularJS,
- Ionic,

Is it possible for them to work as what they are? and how to set it up.

Please notice that my focus right now is to build web application here, not mobile app. And my environment for this is LAMP. Please direct me to the correct way for this. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I worked before with Ionic + AngularJS. You only want the Ionic CSS, right? No problem with that. And Laravel is a Back-End framework, so you can use it and then add extra features with AngularJS. Take your time to set up properly all these frameworks, it is possible, but maybe not easy.